# Key-ids generated automatically on NDB on GAE

Tags: key, app-engine-ndb, digits, auto-generate

I found a statement about the title in a official documentation as below [1](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/concepts/entities).

Here seems to say that auto-generated numeric number is 16 digits long at most.

```
Cloud Datastore can also automatically assign IDs. Cloud Datastore generates a random sequence of unused IDs that are approximately uniformly distributed. Each ID can be up to 16 decimal digits long.
```

Although saying above, according to my experiments, all auto-generated numeric number is FIX 16 digits.
If the documentation is truely saying, is it better to take measures against attributing-bugs?

Anyone is welcome ,who has gotten an auto-generated id less than 15 digits long.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cloud Datastore has a [legacy id allocation policy](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/config/appref#auto_id_policy) which generally has lower numbers than 16 digit, though this is not guaranteed.

In general, if you have requirements around the format of your Cloud Datastore ids, I would recommend developing your own id allocation policy (using string-based ids for your keys). This will let you make guarantees about what your ids look like.

Comment: I understand what you say. It is exactly said that legacy id allocation policy setting make sense in using ids less than 15 digits.
 
However, just what I would like to know is that these ids are actually made automatically with a ndb module or gcp's some restrictions.

Have you heard of those kind of information?

Comment: Ids from either the legacy policy or the current policy are generated by Cloud Datastore backends. The backend reserves the right to change the id allocation scheme as long as it matches the API guarantees ("These keys are guaranteed not to have been returned previously by the data store's internal ID generator, nor will they be returned by future calls to the internal ID generator." [source](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/ndb/creating-entity-keys#numeric_keys)

Comment: I got it. Thank you for your advice.
I decided using allocate_ids() method and that excellently works well so that I hope.